# Fatal error: Declaration of ... must be compatible with

Tags: 8, blocks

```
/**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return [];
  }
```

in BlockBase.php

vs

```
/**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function blockForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state ) {
       $form = parent::blockForm($form, $form_state);

       $form['city'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => $this->t('City'),
        '#default_value' => $this->configuration['city'],
       ];

       return $form; 
    }
```

in CustomWeatherBlock.php

Adding array in first argument as typehint of $form gives above error.
I just need to understand why is it giving an error.Is it because BlockBase is an abstract class and CustomWeatherBlock class extends BlockBase hence it needs to copy exactly the methods name and its arguments (including typehint) ?

Error

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Declaration of
>   Drupal\custom_changes\Plugin\Block\CustomWeatherBlock::blockForm(array
>   $form, Drupal\custom_changes\Plugin\Block\FormStateInterface
>   $form_state) must be compatible with
>   Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase::blockForm($form,
>   Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/d8jsonapi/web/modules/custom/custom_changes/src/Plugin/Block/CustomWeatherBlock.php
>   on line 16

Comment: Because it must conform to its contract. BlockBase implements BlockPluginInterface, where blockForm is declared.

Comment: yes I thought so as per the OOPs concept but wanted a confirmation :) thanks @Kevin

Comment: You will see the same error if you add arguments to the end as well. I only found that by doing `$arg = NULL` will not show the error. Not sure if that is best practice or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BlockBase` implements [BlockPluginInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Block%21BlockPluginInterface.php/interface/BlockPluginInterface/8.5.x), which defines `blockForm()` as follows:

```
public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state);
```

Interfaces are like contracts. Any class that implements an interface (or one of it's descendants) must define all the functions in the interface, and they must be defined exactly as in the interface. This is so that developers can replace classes, but ensure the code will still work, since the function definition will always expect the same values, as defined by the interface.

When you add a typehint to force `$form` to be an array, you break the contract of the interface. The interface says that any value should be allowed for the `$form` argument, but you are saying it must be an array. If you used your code, and a function passed a non-array value, it would cause an error. The interface is there to prevent such errors from happening. This is why you cannot change the function definition.